# Why is it transferring no values to this other sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy values from the sheet "COMP" to another sheet "BOM" in the same workbook but the code below isn't doing that.

The "COMP" sheet has a range "COMP range" which is a table in which the first column is a list of equipment and the rest of the columns contain parts that correspond to these equipments.

I am am writing a code to find a specific equipment and copy  its corresponding parts over to another sheet (in the same workbook) and transpose them.

```
Sub COMP_PARTS()

COMP1 = "EQUIPMENT 1"

        With Worksheets("COMP").Range("COMP_range")
            NOROWS = .Rows.Count
        For I = 1 To NOROWS
            If (.Cells(I, 1) = COMP1) Then
                 For II = 2 To 29

                   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COMP").Cells(I, II).Copy
                  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BOM").Cells(II, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

                  Next II
            End If

        Next I

        End With

End Sub
```

The part of the code that finds the parts works but the two lines of copying and pasting don't work.

When I run the code, It does activate the "BOM" sheet, and I can see the program activating the cells starting on the forth column and second rows down to the 29th row so this shows the transposing part works but I don't see any values. The cells are just blank.

Comment: Aren't you overwriting the values in BOM anyway? (That may not solve the problem of why nothing appears.) Does it matter that `Cells(I, II)` is not necessarily the same as `.Cells(I, 1)` - only if your table starts in A1?

Comment: Also you're achieving the transpose *manually* by switching a column argument `II` to be a row argument. You don't need to `PasteSpecial Transpose:=True`, because you can't transpose a single cell.

Comment: You don't need to use the copy method, just set the cell values equal to each other like this: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BOM").Cells(II,4).Value2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COMP".Cells(I,II).Value2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... to find a specific equipment and copy its corresponding parts ...

This statement seems to indicate that there will only be a single piece of equipment to copy from the COMP worksheet to the BOM worksheet.

```
Sub COMP_PARTS()

    dim COMP1 as string, I as long, II as long

    COMP1 = "EQUIPMENT 1"
    II = 30  '2 to 29 is a total of 30 inclusive cells

    'reference the source named range
    With Worksheets("COMP").Range("COMP_range")

        'Cycle through the rows in column A of the named range
        For I = 1 To .Rows.Count

            'check if the first column in Range("COMP_range") is COMP1
            If .Cells(I, 1) = COMP1 Then

                'reference the total source of the data to transfer
                with .Cells(I, 2).Resize(1, II)
                    'Resize the Target to match the transposed size of the source
                    'Offset the top-left cell of the target here for multiple sources
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BOM").Cells(2, 4).Resize(.Columns.Count, .Rows.Count).OFFSET(0, 0) = _
                        application.transpose(.Value)

                    'If only one, then no need to continue
                    Exit For

                end with

            End If

        Next I

    End With

End Sub
```

If there could be more than a single set of equipment data, remove the `Exit For` and use an incremented integer variable to Offset the target location.